# Display a field other than the foreign key in Cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm creating my first application with Cakephp, I have 2 tables, Users and Requests.

### Users

- Id
- User_name
- Full_names
- Last_name etc

### Requests

- Id
- User_id
- amount etc

I want to display in a table for Requests, amount, Full_names, Last_name, instead of showing the foreign key (User_id). I've used Cakephp conventions, but am stuck on this one, I've tried the $belongsTo approach, but have come undone, please assist.

Comment: and what cake version u using?

Comment: please write your code. $belongsto works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers,
My Models seem to have been in order, I only needed the line below in my View to display the required fields

```
<td><?= h($request->user->last_name) ?></td>
```